# What does this mean: +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:]?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am trying to setup push notifications using Urban Airship and I believe I'm having a problem with the provisioning profiles or ssl certificates. The app is not prompting the user for Push Notifications permissions but I am not getting a 'no valid "aps-environment" entitlement string found for application' message, and I can see the `aps-environment` entitlement in the `.mobileprovision`.

I can't find any documentation on `+[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:]` so I am wondering if anyone knows what that could mean?

Also, the device token is being returned as nil, as logged by Urban Airship:

> [D] -[UAPush updateRegistrationForcefully:] [Line 544] Device token is
>   nil. Registration will be attempted at a later time

There is no Urban Airship code running prior to the `[UAirship takeOff:config]` call, and the app does not crash as a result of the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Urban Airship Crashes in 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635439/urban-airship-crashes-in-2-0)

Comment: This solved by problem in that it made the app receive push notifications again.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app

I don't have an answer however to what +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:]? means.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about Urban Airship I can offer a guess.

`takeOff` ensures that the actual implementation provided in `executeUnsafeTakeoff` only happens once. It makes sure that the current thread is the main thread and then ensures that it only happens once.

Therefore getting an `executeUnsafeTakeoff` error really only tells you that something went wrong, such as if the config`failed to`validate` (see below).

You need to make sure that the app can receive push notifications, as you mentioned.

Here is `takeOff`:

```
+ (void)takeOff {
    [UAirship takeOff:[UAConfig defaultConfig]];
}

+ (void)takeOff:(UAConfig *)config {

    // takeOff needs to be run on the main thread
    if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        NSException *mainThreadException = [NSException exceptionWithName:UAirshipTakeOffBackgroundThreadException
                                                                   reason:@"UAirship takeOff must be called on the main thread."
                                                                 userInfo:nil];
        [mainThreadException raise];
    }

    dispatch_once(&takeOffPred_, ^{
        [UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:config];
    });
}
```

Here is `executeUnsafeTakeoff`:

```
/*
 * This is an unsafe version of takeOff - use takeOff: instead for dispatch_once
 */
+ (void)executeUnsafeTakeOff:(UAConfig *)config {
    // Airships only take off once!
    if (_sharedAirship) {
        return;
    }

    [UAirship setLogLevel:config.logLevel];

    _sharedAirship = [[UAirship alloc] init];
    _sharedAirship.config = config;

    // Ensure that app credentials have been passed in
    if (![config validate]) {

        UA_LERR(@"The AirshipConfig.plist file is missing and no application credentials were specified at runtime.");

        // Bail now. Don't continue the takeOff sequence.
        return;
    }

    UA_LINFO(@"App Key: %@", _sharedAirship.config.appKey);
    UA_LINFO(@"App Secret: %@", _sharedAirship.config.appSecret);
    UA_LINFO(@"Server: %@", _sharedAirship.config.deviceAPIURL);

    if (config.automaticSetupEnabled) {

        _sharedAirship.appDelegate = [[UAAppDelegateProxy alloc ]init];

        //swap pointers with the initial app delegate
        @synchronized ([UIApplication sharedApplication]) {
            _sharedAirship.appDelegate.originalAppDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            _sharedAirship.appDelegate.airshipAppDelegate = [[UAAppDelegate alloc] init];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate = _sharedAirship.appDelegate;
        }
    }


    // Build a custom user agent with the app key and name
    [_sharedAirship configureUserAgent];

    // Set up analytics
    _sharedAirship.analytics = [[UAAnalytics alloc] initWithConfig:_sharedAirship.config];
    [_sharedAirship.analytics delayNextSend:UAAnalyticsFirstBatchUploadInterval];

    /*
     * Handle Debug Options
     */

    //For testing, set this value in AirshipConfig to clear out
    //the keychain credentials, as they will otherwise be persisted
    //even when the application is uninstalled.
    if (config.clearKeychain) {

        UA_LDEBUG(@"Deleting the keychain credentials");
        [UAKeychainUtils deleteKeychainValue:_sharedAirship.config.appKey];

        UA_LDEBUG(@"Deleting the UA device ID");
        [UAKeychainUtils deleteKeychainValue:kUAKeychainDeviceIDKey];
    }

    if (!config.inProduction) {
        [_sharedAirship validate];
    }

    if (config.cacheDiskSizeInMB > 0) {
        UA_LINFO("Registering UAURLProtocol");
        [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[UAURLProtocol class]];
    }

    // The singleton is now ready for use!
    _sharedAirship.ready = true;


    //create/setup user (begin listening for device token changes)
    [[UAUser defaultUser] initializeUser];

}
```